# Firebase Functions With Express Failed to decode param %CO

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

There is a solution to this error without the use of Firebase [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125216/express-handling-urierror-failed-to-decode-param) when using `app.listen(8080)` however this does not work while serving in cloud functions with `exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)`

Here is a simple reproduction code

```
const app = express();
app.get('**', (req, res) => res.send('working'));
app.use((err, req, res, next) => res.redirect('/404'));
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app) // doesnt work
// app.listen(5000) // works
```

How do you go about catching this error in firebase functions? I would like the redirect to work.

firebase test: `firebase serve --only functions`

express serve: `node index.js`

URL to test: `http://localhost:5000/%CO`

Note that the additional `%CO` is the one that cannot be decoded by express. This error is caught while serving with the express method but not with the firebase functions method.

As this seems like a bug, I have also created an [issue here on github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3891) incase I find no workaround on it.

Comment: I inspected the firebase logs and found why the error is happening but I dont know how to go about it yet. `AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:172:12)` is catching `decodeURIComponent(val)` error before express receives the request. How can i override this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of `app` in `exports.`

```
exports.newApp = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Comment: Sorry this is not the reason, the exported variable cannot affect the local variable

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps), the correct way of using an Express app with Firebase Functions is to pass the application to a Function like:

```
// Expose Express API as a single Cloud Function:
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Listening to a port for requests does [not apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547157/t) when running through Firebase Functions. As for how to catch errors when passing your app to a function, it’s done in the same way as the question you referenced as far as I have [reviewed](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/555). You can catch errors by using [Express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) while using [Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/improve-your-cloud-function-implementations-using-express-js-middlewares-b8b30cfd00e5).

Moreover, implementing redirects with Firebase Functions is explained in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071338/), which makes use of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects) to configure how to redirect by modifying the `firebase.json` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have editted the question to make it more clear since your answer did not touch on the issue that I am facing. The serving works but express middleware doesnt work while using firebase

Comment: I read your comment under the post, and based on this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347239/), it seems you are in a similar scenario. Instead of catching the error with an error handler, you should create app middleware which catches the error and redirects users to your desired page. I would recommend following the guide about [routing middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).